# Comments sorted by oldest first

Tags: comments

I've set my comments display order to be oldest first. When there are more comments than the number allowed per page, the comments are spread across 2 pages and a pager is provided.

My issue is that when you first come to the node to see the comments, you see the older comments. You then have to click to the 2nd page to see the latest comments.

I understand from a logical perspective why it works this way, but I don't think its the best for usability. How can I make it so when you arrive at a node you see the last page of comments by default? Do I need to use a views override? 
Thanks

Note, in case its of interest this point has been raised by the drupal experts lullabot:
http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-usability-comment-configuration

> While shorter pages are generally more usable, setting the number of
>   comments per page to a low number comes in conflict with my
>   recommendation of setting the display order to oldest first. With a
>   small number, it is very possible that the latest comments will not be
>   listed on the initial page and will require several clicks and
>   scrolling to get to them. This is bad. A better solution is to set the
>   comments per page as high as possible. Users will intuitively scroll
>   down to find the latest stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this with a view. I was about to post you a long detailed post on how to get this done, but found this [post on the subject that explains it in great detail](http://www.daobydesign.com/blog/tips/drupal/customize-drupals-recent-comments-block/).

Basically, you create a view and from there you have sort options available for your comment fields.

Credits to DAO Design for the blog post, hope that helps, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[Comment Goodness](http://drupal.org/project/comment_goodness) module does just that. [Sort Comments](http://drupal.org/project/sort_comments) is another option, but as of now only has a development release.

Here's a snapshot of [Comment Goodness](http://drupal.org/project/comment_goodness) module, borrowed from the site.
[image]

Comment: but when enable this module the date of comment disappeared to me !!!

Comment: You might want to check if there's a *.tpl.php file within the module. You can copy that into your themes folder and override comment output. You can also use a Devel module to sort through variables to see what's causing it. If all fails, file a bug with the appropriate Drupal module. Sometimes it's as simple as calling a hook or configuring module settings. Hope this will get you started!

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, but waste 4 hour :(