# sort comments descending programmatically

Tags: comments, theming

I want to sort all comment descending  programmatically, I found this [Comments sorted by oldest first](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19224/comments-sorted-by-oldest-first) but I dont want use those modules or views solution.
anybody know how can I sort comment descending programmatically?
I means comments in below node(contents) , first ideal is get comments related to node by query and set `orderby DESC`  but everything show reversed in thread mode, **replies come above comment !!!**.

Comment: Comments attached to a node or All comments in the website ?

Comment: comments attached to node in view of node

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = db_select('comment') ->fields('comment', array('cid')) ->condition('nid', arg(1), '=');
$query->orderBy('created', 'DESC');
$result = $query->execute();
$cids = $result->fetchCol();
$comments=comment_load_multiple($cids);
foreach($comments as $comment)  {
  //do some stuff with the comment
}
?>
```

Comment: but do u think about how they come in thread mode ? replay placed above comment !!! (everything reversed>, tnx for you attention but this is not complete solution.

Comment: Can you update your question with above details which will help others ? I mean thread mode..

Comment: sure , I will update it .